# Pure JavaScript onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to learn NodeJs and MongoDb and master JavaScript (using js to create the whole GUI and functionality) I think I've got Node but I'm stuck a problem to add `onclick` events to the GUI and in the same time have a nice and easy to maintain code. Just started from scratch so the code is really short for now.

This code some how fires `onclick` event during page loading only ...

```
var httpRequest;
document.body.onload = populateTable;

var userListData = [];

// Fill table with data
function populateTable() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        try {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
              if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var res = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                userListData = res;
                res.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                    var tr = newElement("tr");
                    tr.appendChild(newElement("td")).appendChild(newElement("a", {href : "#", class : "linkshowuser", rel : element.username, innerHTML : element.username, onclick : showUserInfoObject(element)}));
                    tr.appendChild(newElement("td", {innerHTML : element.email}));
                    tr.appendChild(newElement("td")).appendChild(newElement("a", {href : "#", class : "linkshowuser", rel : element._id, innerHTML : "delete", onclick : showUserInfo(element.username)}));
                    document.getElementById("tbody").appendChild(tr);
                });
              } else 
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', '/users/userlist');
    httpRequest.send();    
};

function newElement (type, attrs) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    for(var a in attrs)
        element[a] = attrs[a];
    return element;
}

function findUserByName (username) {
    for (var i in userListData)
        if (userListData[i].username == username)
            return userListData[i];
}

function showUserInfo (username) {
    console.log("Delete?", findUserByName(username));
}

function showUserInfoObject (user) {
    console.log("UserName", user);
}
```

Result currently only 2 users exist in the db so it fires both functions on it owns twice for each user since there are two links both with onclick event)

```
UserName Object {_id: "55dc7a2c20b546741e030902", username: "test1", email: "test1@test.com", fullname: "Bob Smith", age: 27…}
test.js:47 Delete? Object {_id: "55dc7a2c20b546741e030902", username: "test1", email: "test1@test.com", fullname: "Bob Smith", age: 27…}
test.js:51 UserName Object {_id: "55dc9844135f4517d5388b24", username: "test1", email: "test1@test.com", fullname: "Bob Smith", age: 27…}
test.js:47 Delete? Object {_id: "55dc7a2c20b546741e030902", username: "test1", email: "test1@test.com", fullname: "Bob Smith", age: 27…}
```

How ever I manage to create a work around but it looks really ugly:

```
var httpRequest;
document.body.onload = populateTable;

var userListData = [];

// Fill table with data
function populateTable() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        try {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
              if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var res = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                userListData = res;
                res.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                    var tr = newElement("tr");
                    tr.appendChild(newElement("td")).appendChild(newElement("a", {href : "#", class : "linkshowuser", rel : element.username, innerHTML : element.username, onclick : onClickValue("showUserInfoObject", [element])}));
                    tr.appendChild(newElement("td", {innerHTML : element.email}));
                    tr.appendChild(newElement("td")).appendChild(newElement("a", {href : "#", class : "linkshowuser", rel : element._id, innerHTML : "delete", onclick : onClickValue("showUserInfo", [element.username])}));
                    document.getElementById("tbody").appendChild(tr);
                });
              } else 
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', '/users/userlist');
    httpRequest.send();    
};

function newElement (type, attrs) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    for(var a in attrs) {
        if(attrs[a] === attrs.onclick)
            element.setAttribute("onclick", attrs[a]);
        else element[a] = attrs[a];
    }
    return element;
}

function findUserByName (username) {
    for (var i in userListData)
        if (userListData[i].username == username)
            return userListData[i];
}

function onClickValue (functionName, args) {
    args = args.map(function (arg) {
        switch (typeof arg) {
            case "string":
                return "\'" + arg + "\'";
            case "object": 
                return JSON.stringify(arg);
            case "number":
                return arg;
            case "boolean":
                return arg;
            case "undefined":
                return arg;
        }
    });
    functionName += '(';
    for(var arg in args)
        functionName += args[arg];
    return functionName + ')';
}

function showUserInfo (username) {
    console.log("Delete?", findUserByName(username));
}

function showUserInfoObject (user) {
    console.log("UserName", user);
}
```

It produces the expected result, prints only when link gets clicked.

Is there a good looking and easy to maintain way to do this?

Comment: Forgot to add the real question, so here it is : "Is there a good looking and easy to maintain way to do it ?"

Comment: @Ivo Stratev You can edit your question, there's no need to add comments for this. Your question is rather asking for code review and therefore doesn't really fit to StackOverflow, It would be maybe better to consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assign event handlers as follows...

`onclick : showUserInfoObject(element)`

When assigning, it's just looking for the name of the function. Which is why your code executes on assignment.

`onclick : showUserInfoObject`

The parameters of the function are defined by the event, usually an event object. You cannot provide those on assignment, unless you do something like this, but I wouldn't recommend it, based on the question...

`onclick : function () {showUserInfo(element.username);}`

Event handlers are typically assigned like this, without the "on"...

`newElement.addEventListener('click', showUserInfo, false);`

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener) for MDN reference...

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is with what i started on first place with and this is what the result was:  `newElement.addEventListener('click', showUserInfo);` => undefined, `newElement.addEventListener('click', showUserInfo(element.username)); `=> the same as `onclick : showUserInfo(element.username)`.